# gopls replace variable in the entire project

Tags: go

The question born from the fact that `gorename` does not support modules. There is a replacement tool called `gopls`, but the example is not exhaustive so I'm wondering if there is way to rename a variable in the entire project (otherwise I'm failing to understand the usefulness of the rename part)

> gopls rename --help says:
>
> Usage: rename [flags]
>
> ```
> Example:
>
> gopls rename helper/helper.go:8:6  
> gopls rename helper/helper.go:#53
> ```

Is there a way to rename a variable in the entire project like `gorename` is able to do?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use gopls as an LSP server to integrate with your editor. Your editor should provide an lsp-rename command to conveniently invoke the rename functionality.

As for using gopls rename on the command line, if you have this module:

```
--- go.mod ---
module foo

--- foo.go ---
package foo
var Foo = 123
```

Inside the module's directory, run `gopls rename -d foo.go:3:5 Hello` to preview the diff ("3:5" means line 3, column 5):

```
% gopls rename -d foo.go:3:5 Hello
--- /Users/muir/scratch/foo/foo.go.orig
+++ /Users/muir/scratch/foo/foo.go
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 package foo

-var Foo = 123
+var Hello = 123
```

Then run `gopls rename -w foo.go:3:5 Hello` to write out the changes. Assuming you are using a recent version of gopls, this will rename within the entire module.